# Regenerate conflicts of completed TFS merges

Tags: tfs, merge

I have recently discovered that I was using my third party diff/merge tool incorrectly when resolving conflicts encountered merging from the trunk to my team branch. As far as I know, only files that were merged in the merge tool were affected. I know how to use tf merge /force to re-do a merge, but I don't want to re-merge every file if I can avoid it, just the ones that I had to merge manually. Is there any way to get a list of such files now, long after the merge changesets have been checked in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, TFS does not track any data about which files were resolved using a merge tool.  Whether a file was merged manually or automatically it is still just recorded as a "merge" in TFS.

Comment: Is there a way to "go back in time" and perform the merge in the state in which the codebase (branches) existed at the time? I guess I should just try it :)

Comment: I attempted to get as of the changeset prior to the merge checkin, and force a merge. I still got a bunch of conflicts that didn't happen the first time around (and never changed in our branch, other than merges).